# Updating Database from DataGridView with combo box not working in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb, oledbcommand

Updating Database from DataGridView with combo box not working in vb.net
I want to update by doing a combobox filter for the database column "INVNO"

please best solution. another one in the code below and do I need to use using-statement?

Thanks

```
Friend Class DatabaseManager
    Private connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStr").ConnectionString
    Private conn As OleDbConnection
    Private adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private builder As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Private threadHelper As Thread
Public Sub New()
        conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function FillData(ByVal command As String) As DataTable
            If command.Trim().Length < 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("Command text is empty")
            End If
            Dim _ad As New OleDbDataAdapter(command, conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        _ad.Fill(dt)
        adapter = _ad
        If threadHelper IsNot Nothing AndAlso threadHelper.IsAlive Then
            threadHelper.Abort()
        End If
        threadHelper = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Do_Work))
        threadHelper.Start()

        Return dt
    End Function

    Private Sub Do_Work()
        builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
        adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
        adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand()
    End Sub
    Public Function UpdateData(ByVal dt As DataTable) As Integer
        If adapter Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Parameter adapter is null")
        End If
        Return adapter.Update(dt)
    End Function
    End Class
```

```
 Private Sub LoadData()
            Dim sql As String = String.Empty
            If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
''Parameters' is not a member of 'String'
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INVNO", CStr(ComboBox1.SelectedValue))
                dtData = db.FillData("SELECT * FROM DEMOTABLEPRODUCT WHERE INVNO = @INVNO")
                gvMain.DataSource = dtData
            End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateData()
            Try
                Dim i As Integer = db.UpdateData(dtData)
                MessageBox.Show(i & " : records updated successfully")
            Catch err As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
            Me.LoadData()
        End Sub
```

I was expecting the combobox to do filters

Comment: Is this parameter `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue` getting passed into FillData?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer , 
Yes, that's right, so `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue` fills the datagridview but I haven't managed to do it is there any solution

Comment: @AndrewMortimer , `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue` I found an error `Parameters' is not a member of 'String'`

Comment: Yeah I can't see where you declare the command object, but you're definitely not passing it into the FillData, so FillData isn't taking the parameter value into account.

Comment: Where exactly are you declaring Command?  Looks to me like in some places you are treating the same variable as a String (param in FillData()), then in others as a OleDbCommand(Command.Parameters).    Suspect you probably want to turn Option Strict On then fix all the errors that it highlights.  Option Strict will stop you from mish mashing variable types